# ms access - How to edit dlookup query textbox in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

The form retrieves data from a query to a textbox which needs to be editable so that input data can be saved to a table. To do this, I left the textbox control source blank and on form open module wrote `me.text1870 = dlookup(...`

To edit this textbox I wrote the following code:

```
DoCmd.runsql ("Update tableName Set qnty = " forms![frmName]!text1870")
```

But it is not updating the table or it updates the entire table with same value.

Comment: You need to qualify which record to update. Do you have a unique ID on the row of your form? If so, add a WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks. I tried to but I'm not sure where the error is: DoCmd.RunSQL ("Update tbl_data set Units = '" & [strVal] & "'" where [Fin_yr] = '" & me.Fin_Yr & "AND [Qtr] = '" & me.Qtr & "AND [Prov] = '" & me.Prov & "AND [Sub_Prog] = '" & '1.1a Ind subsidies (0-R3500)' & "'")

Comment: You are missing several single quotes, plus some spaces, and I don't have a clue what "& '1.1a Ind subsidies (0-R3500)' " is all about. Are any of the fields where you enclose in single quotes Numeric? If so, don't use the single quote. Here's what you need  except for the end mentioned above: "Update tbl_data set Units = '" & [strVal] & "' where [Fin_yr] = '" & Me.Fin_Yr & "' AND [Qtr] = '" & Me.Qtr & "' AND [Prov] = '" & Me.Prov & "' AND [Sub_Prog] = '"